# When creating a T4 template, how can the app config and other file resources be utilized?

Tags: nhibernate, t4

I have a T4 template that I am trying to create that will code gen lookup values from a database via Nhibernate. My problem is my data access layer uses the path of the Nhibernate configuration in order to compile the configuration upon startup (a static constructor).

I don't know how to make t4 "see" this file path so that when my code gen runs it can get this configuration file. Nor do I know how to make t4 "see" my configuration manager class; which contains the app setting that lists the path to the nhibernate xml file.

I have two configuration files, one for SQL Server and one for sqlite. The configuration file needs to be in the root directory of the executing assembly in order to nhibernate to compile the configuration.

It seems like my template won't be able to use the high level business layer to select the data from the database, rather I may have to copy all the nhibernate configuration code into the template as well (ugh).

My DB wrapper:

```
private class DBSingleton
{
    static DBSingleton()
    {
        string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBConfigFileFullPath"];
        NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration cfg = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration().Configure(path);
        cfg.AddInputStream(HbmSerializer.Default.Serialize(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Plan))));
        instance = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
    }
    internal static readonly ISessionFactory instance;
}
```

And my template:

```
<#
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
string path = Host.ResolvePath(@"..\DB.UnitTest\App.config");
    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Add(
    "DBConfigFileFullPath", path);
//System.Configuration.ConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ConfigurationFileMap(path); //Path to your config file
//System.Configuration.Configuration configuration = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(fileMap);


ReferenceValueBL bl = new ReferenceValueBL();
List<ReferenceValue> refVals = bl.Select(); <- problem occurs here
foreach(ReferenceValue rv in refVals)
{
    Write("Public ");
    Write(rv.ReferenceValueCode.GetType().Name);
    Write(" ");
    Write(rv.ReferenceValueCode);
    Write(" = ");
    Write(rv.ReferenceValueCode);
}

#>
```

My problem occurs when the bl variable tries to call select(). That's when the DBSingleton is initialized. It throws an error saying the app setting is null. If I hard code the relative file path in the DB class to just be ./Dbconfig.xml it still throws an error because the executing assembly doesn't have that file in it's local directory.

How do other people handle getting t4 to use app/web config files without reading from the config file within the template and then injecting a connection string into the DAL? I don't have that luxury. The file has to be either placed in a readable location or t4 has to know to look somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

> How do other people handle getting t4 to use app/web config files without reading from the config file within the template and then injecting a connection string into the DAL?

You could perhaps convert your text template into [runtime text template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844259.aspx) by setting Properties | Custom Tool to "TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor".

Afterwards the entire code generation process would be encapsulated within standard class which will have `TransformText` method which produces the resulting string - you can then write it into file of your liking.

Nice thing is that the template class is partial, so you can add implementation of some custom methods. Something like this perhaps:

```
public partial class RuntimeTextTemplate1
{
    public string TransformText(string someParameter)
    {
        // Do something with someParameter, initialize class field
        // with its value and later use this field in your t4 file.
        // You also have access to ConfigurationManager.AppSettings here.
        return TransformText();
    }
}
```

Also, this:

```
foreach(ReferenceValue rv in refVals)
{
    Write("Public ");
    Write(rv.ReferenceValueCode.GetType().Name);
    Write(" ");
    Write(rv.ReferenceValueCode);
    Write(" = ");
    Write(rv.ReferenceValueCode);
}
```

Could be rewritten as:

```
foreach(ReferenceValue rv in refVals)
{
#>
Public <#= rv.ReferenceValueCode.GetType().Name #> <#= rv.ReferenceValueCode #> = <#= rv.ReferenceValueCode #>
<#+
}
```